# Hadoop - BLOCK* blk_XXXXX on 10.XX.XX.XX size XX does not belongs to any file

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I deleted multiple old files (HiveLogs/MR-Job intermediate files) from HDFS location `/temp/hive-user/hive_2015*`.

After that, I noticed my four node cluster is responding very slow and having the following issue.

I re-started my cluster, it worked fine for 3-4 hours, and then again it started giving same issue as follows:

1. Hadoopdfs health page is getting loaded very slowly.
2. File browsing is very slow
3. Namenode logs getting full with  "Blocks does not belongs to any File".
4. All operation to my cluster is slow.

I found it could be because of I deleted hdfs files, according to HDFS JIRA- 7815 and 7480, as I deleted huge numbers of file Namenode could not delete blocks properly. As Namenode was busy with multiple deletions tasks. This is an existing bug with older version of Hadoop (older than 2.6.0).

Can anyone please suggest quick fix without upgrading my hadoop cluster or patch installation?

How can I identify those orphan blocks and delete them from Hadoop FS?

Comment: Following thing can be done on above issue-  1)Solution is keep cluster idle for sometime and don't do any heavy operation(Write Operation). because NM get busy, not able to handle that bulk delete and current transactions simultaneously. 2) Check Hadoop UI see blocks and block pool used are evenly distributed on each node.